# Console print a scaling square with roatated square in the middle

Tags: python, python-3.x

I really am not sure how to explain my question in a title; a graphic will be best.

I've been given this problem as something to play around with in class, so far only one person has managed to achieve a solution, and it's a very complex one.
While I've spoken to him (The best we can manage, his english isn't great), I'd like to come up with my own solution, but I need some pointers, or at least new ideas..

The problem is this:

```
n=5
0 3 5 5 3 0
3 5     5 3
5         5
5         5
3 5     5 3
0 3 5 5 3 0
```

With 'n' being an input value.

So far I've got this;

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
while True:
    n = int(input("Enter a size : "))
    z = "+"

    for i in range(n*2): # ROWS
        for j in range(n*2): # COLUMNS
            if i == 0 or j == 0 or i == n*2 - 1 or j == n*2 - 1: # OUTLINE
                    print(z, end=" ")
            elif j < n-i: # TOP LEFT
                    print(z, end=" ")
            elif j >= n+i or i >= n+j: # TOP RIGHT + BOTTOM LEFT
                    print(z, end=" ")
            elif j >= n*2-i+n-1 and i >= n*2-j+n-1: # BOTTOM RIGHT
                    print(z, end=" ")
            else:
                print(" ", end=" ")
        print()
```

Whitch outputs this;

```
Enter a size : 5
+ + + + + + + + + + 
+ + + +     + + + + 
+ + +         + + + 
+ +             + + 
+                 + 
+                 + 
+ +             + + 
+ + +         + + + 
+ + + +     + + + + 
+ + + + + + + + + +
```

The next step is to replace "z" with an equation for the places in the box I guess. But I've no idea where to start (And my math is a little rusty)

Comment: Your example and output are not consistent for inputs of `n = 5`. This is also not a very good fit for Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far (to replace `z`)? What is the pattern that the numbers follow?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure where to ask. And I am aware examples don't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, and not in a way I was expecting, tbh. I'd call it a dirty hack.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
__author__ = "Luke Jones"
__copyright__ = "Copyleft, do what you want with it"
__license__ = "GPL"
__version__ = "0.0.1"

while True:
    startV = int(input("Enter a size : "))
    array1=[]
    array2=[]
    for i in range(1,startV+1,2):
        array1.append(i)
    array2 = list(array1)
    array2.reverse()
    n = len(array1)

    for i in range(n*2): # ROWS
        for j in range(n*2): # COLUMNS
            if j < n-i: # TOP LEFT
                print(array1[j+i], end=" ")

            elif j >= n+i: # TOP RIGHT
                print(array2[j-n-i], end=" ")

            elif i >= n+j: # BOTTOM LEFT
                print(array2[i-n-j], end=" ")

            elif i >= n*2-j+n-1 and not i >= n*2-j+n:
                #print("X",end=" ")
                for q in range(n*2-j):
                    print(array2[q], end=" ")
            else:
                print(" ", end=" ")
        print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking a guess, I suppose this is what you mean:

```
def square(n):
    def row(i, n):
        l = [str(x) if x <= n else ' ' for x in range(i, i+n)]
        return l + l[::-1]
    top = [row(i, n) for i in range(1, n+1)]
    return '\n'.join(' '.join(r) for r in (top + top[::-1]))

while True:
    n = int(input("> "))
    print(square(n))
```

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting way of doing it.
I wouldn't have thought of using functions within a list. Nor would I have thought of using nested functions..